# "Error in mkRespMod(fr, family = family) : response must be numeric "

Tags: r, glm, lme4, mixed-models

I'm trying to run the following `glmer` model:

```
glmer(
    formula = 
      as.factor(wheezing_InD) ~ 
      age_InD + 
      (1|countryfactor),
    family=poisson(link="log"),
    data = Data46)
```

But I keep getting the following error code:

```
 Error in mkRespMod(fr, family = family) : response must be numeric
```

Does anyone know how I can get around this? I understand it's because my response variable is in factorised form. It runs in an `as.numeric(as.factor(wheezing_InD))` form but I'm not sure I can have it in numeric and be able to interpret the output - I think it needs to be as a factor variable (though I may be wrong).

Here is a sample of the data in `dput` form:

```
structure(list(wheezing_InD = c("No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"), age_InD = c(55L, 24L, 23L, 
30L, 40L, 43L, 37L, 38L, 18L, 23L, 28L, 33L, 27L, 54L, 23L, 23L, 
42L, 48L, 31L, 18L), countryfactor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("cameroon", "ghana", "kenya"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

And in `str` form:

```
    'data.frame':   20 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ wheezing_InD : chr  "No" "Yes" "Yes" "No" ...
 $ age_InD      : int  55 24 23 30 40 43 37 38 18 23 ...
 $ countryfactor: Factor w/ 3 levels "cameroon","ghana",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to apply `binomial` family model instead of `poisson` one. The Poisson regression is used to model a count variable (which should be numerical) while you are interested in the binary dependent variable.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. Eventually I went with coding the variables as "0,1" and persisting with the poisson family and that has worked! The only issue is my model gets stuck "computing confidence intervals" and won't progress past this point - so I have to manually abort the code. Is this an issue you would happen to know anything about?